# selected UITableViewCell data is null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

Table is showing the list of countries. But when i tried to retrieve the data its returning null value. I am trying store the `cell.textlabel.text` into a string but worrying with null

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    }
    jsonDict = [newarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"countryName"];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"country is %@",cell.textLabel.text);
    cell.textLabel.text=CountryString;
}
```

Comment: note that when creating the cell you are using a different identifier

Comment: what is this CountryString, u were not move the any value to CountryString in didselectrow

Comment: forget about country string am getting null value in console with NSLog(@"country is %@",cell.textLabel.text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  jsonDict = [newarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

CountryString=[jsonDict objectForKey:@"countryName"]

NSLog(@"country is %@", CountryString);


}
```

your cell identifier also different

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";  //here mention the correct one use either `MyCell` or `CellIdentifier`

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil)
{
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

 }
jsonDict = [newarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"countryName"];
return cell;

}
```